# How to take the key from Array[(String, Iterable[Int])]?

Tags: arrays, scala, for-loop

I have an array: `Array((Jason,CompactBuffer(25)), (Emily,CompactBuffer(16)),...` and I need just to print out names from the array: *Jason, Emily,...* How to do that in scala?

Comment: `println(array.map(_._1).mkString(","))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print each one in separate line any of those:

```
array.foreach(tuple => println(tuple._1)
array.foreach { case (name, _) => println(name) }
array.map(_._1).foreach(println)
```

to make a string with custom separator you can do

```
println(array.map(_._1).mkString("<separator>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `array.map(_._1).mkString(", ")`